# Unit Testing Angular component with service : Cannot read property 'diagonisticData' of undefi

Tags: json, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-components

I am new to angular testing. I have a component, nested json and a service. The app works fine but during testing values are not being populated into the component. Please help.I have attached the service, json object,component and spec file.
I am not sure if I am following the right approach in spec file.
**App component -Hub-Details-component.ts**

```
export class HubDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
ngOnInit(): void {}
public jsonData:any = []
public diagnosticsData:any = [];
public dummy:any = [];
public hubData:any;
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
handleData() 
{
  this.dataService.getData()
    .subscribe(response =>{
          if(response!=null)
          {
        this.jsonData=response;
        console.log(this.jsonData);
          this.dummy=this.jsonData.result;
        
        console.log(this.dummy);
          this.diagnosticsData=this.dummy.diagnosticData;
        const DataArray = [];
        for(const element in this.diagnosticsData)
        {

            DataArray.push({
                id:element,
                name:this.diagnosticsData[element]
            });
        }
        console.log(DataArray);
        this.hubData=DataArray;

      }
      });
   }
}
```

DataService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'})
export class DataService {
  public url = '/assets/Data/Data.json'
  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }
  getData = () => {
     const url = 'assets/Data/Data.json';
     return this.http.get(url);
 }}
```

json file

```
{
  "result"
   {
     "abc"
      {
        "name" :"abc",
        "tag" : "xyz",
        "status": "qwe"
      }
   }
 }
```

spec.ts

```
it('should get data from dataservice',fakeAsync(()=>{
const fixture = 
TestBed.createComponent(HubDetailsComponent);
const component = 
fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
const service = 
fixture.debugElement.injector.get(DataService);
let spy_getPosts = 
spyOn(service,'getData').and.callFake(() => {
        return of([{"result"{
                          "abc"
                           {
                           "name" :"abc",
                           "tag" : "xyz",
                           "status": "qwe"
                            }
                          }
                       }]).pipe(delay(2000));});
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.handleData();
    tick(2000);
  
    expect(component.jsonData).toEqual([{
                         {"result"{
                          "abc"
                           {
                           "name" :"abc",
                           "tag" : "xyz",
                           "status": "qwe"
                            }
                          }
                       }
        
    }]);
}));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you do `console.log(this.dummy )`, what do you get? I am thinking that is undefined.

Comment: @AliF50  the problem is during testing data from service is not being passed on to the component function only . so starting from jsonData everything is null. probably the fault is in spec file on spyon since app in usual is working fine

Comment: Try removing the `delay(2000)`

Comment: @AliF50 Thanks , I was able to solve the error i was returning an array through spyon while the actual return value was observable .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// In your spec file, mock the service;

@Injectable()
class MockDataService extends DataService {
  getData() {
    const mockData = {
       result: {
          diagnosticData: [
             { mock1: 'value1' },
             { mock2: 'value2' }
          ]
       }
    }
    return of(mockData);
  }
}

describe('Your Component Name you are testing', () => {
  let dataService;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [...yourImports],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: DataService,
          useClass: MockDataService
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    dataService = TestBed.get(DataService);
  }));

  

 // Now your test case: 

it('should call #handleData() method', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'handleData').and.callThrough();
  component.handleData();
  expect(component.handleData).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

// Thats it. You do not need to do anything else;

})
```